# Parse none uniform JSON Python

Tags: python, json

I have trouble getting "remoteAddress" only when I need it. This output is generated by another API so I can't edit it. Just to be clear I want to split up the data of the 2 processes. Sorry if it's a repost, I couldn't find a similar post.

```
{
   "family": "INET6",
   "pid": 835,
   "localAddress": {
       "ip": "127.0.0.1",
       "port": 44082
   },
   "processName": "avahi-daemon",
   "state": "NONE",
   "type": "SOCK_DGRAM"
},
{
   "family": "INET",
   "pid": 22624,
   "localAddress": {
       "ip": "0.0.0.0",
       "port": 631
   },
   "remoteAddress": {
       "ip": "x.x.x.x",
       "port": 443
   },
   "processName": "gitkraken",
   "state": "ESTABLISHED",
   "type": "SOCK_STREAM"
 }
```

Edit: It needs to be dynamic so I can't just search for "remoteAddress". I'm parsing GRR flows, diffirent flows have diffirent keys that can be missing.

Comment: `if "remoteAddress" in your_dict: ...`?

Comment: It needs to be dynamic so I can't just search for "remoteAddress". I'm parsing GRR flows, diffirent flows have diffirent keys that can be missing.

Comment: `if dynamic_key in your_dict: ...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict.get`

**Ex:**

```
data = [{
   "family": "INET6",
   "pid": 835,
   "localAddress": {
       "ip": "127.0.0.1",
       "port": 44082
   },
   "processName": "avahi-daemon",
   "state": "NONE",
   "type": "SOCK_DGRAM"
},
{
   "family": "INET",
   "pid": 22624,
   "localAddress": {
       "ip": "0.0.0.0",
       "port": 631
   },
   "remoteAddress": {
       "ip": "x.x.x.x",
       "port": 443
   },
   "processName": "gitkraken",
   "state": "ESTABLISHED",
   "type": "SOCK_STREAM"
 }
]
res = [i.get("remoteAddress") for i in data]
print(res)
print(filter(None, res))
```

**Output:**

```
[None, {'ip': 'x.x.x.x', 'port': 443}]
[{'ip': 'x.x.x.x', 'port': 443}]
```

Comment: This is great. I have a loop for all key's as it needs to be dynamic. One more questions: this gives me 'n' arrays of 'x' values right? So how do I get all 'xi' in the same array? eg: ["a","b"] and [1,2] need to become ["a", 1] and ["b", 2]. Hope it makes sense. Again dynamic pls (sometimes my arrays are 2 long sometimes 5 or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these two dictionaries are in stored a **list**, like

```
data = [{
   "family": "INET6",
   "pid": 835,
   "localAddress": {
       "ip": "127.0.0.1",
       "port": 44082
   },
   "processName": "avahi-daemon",
   "state": "NONE",
   "type": "SOCK_DGRAM"
},
{
   "family": "INET",
   "pid": 22624,
   "localAddress": {
       "ip": "0.0.0.0",
       "port": 631
   },
   "remoteAddress": {
       "ip": "x.x.x.x",
       "port": 443
   },
   "processName": "gitkraken",
   "state": "ESTABLISHED",
   "type": "SOCK_STREAM"
 }]
```

Then this code should return the **value** stored in the key **"remote address"**

```
for dictionary in data:
    if "remoteAddress" in dictionary:
        print(dictionary.get("remoteAddress"))
```